# Sequence Contains no matching elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have a SubCategory model in an mvc 4 application for a shirt shop and I am wanting to populate the database using seed data when I ran my application, I recieve Error Message: "Sequence Contains no matching elements"

My code:

```
    var subCategories = new List<SubCategory>
        {
    new SubCategory{Category = categories.Single(s => s.Name == "Animals") , Name "Animal Prints"},
    new SubCategory{Category = categories.Single(s => s.Name == "Animals") , Name = "Bugs"},
        };
```

Comment: `categories.Single(s => s.Name == "Animals")` - there was no category with the name "Animals". While you could use `SingleOrDefault`, that might end up with a NullReferenceException (or incorrect category tree) later - might want to ensure that the category exists, and/or find out why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you don't have any entry in you categories with name as "Animals"
if you wanted to check it

```
   var categorie = categories.where(s => s.Name == "Animals").SingleOrDefault();

   if(categories == null)
   {
     // db is not seeded with categories do something
   }
   else
   {     

        var subCategories = new List<SubCategory>
        {
           new SubCategory{Category = categorie  , Name "Animal Prints"},
           new SubCategory{Category = categorie  , Name = "Bugs"},
        };
   }
```